# Stop Parse sdk to open safari popup for Facebook Login

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I updated to parse v1.9.0 and now instead of showing an alert when trying to login with facebook, it shows Safari webview pop to login with facebook. This will be annoying for users to enter all the facebook info to login. How can I get that alert to show again, so they just click Allow to login?